# Ldap connection with Openstack could not find user : admin

Tags: ldap, openstack, openldap, keystone

I am confuring Ldap with openstack but when openstack send request to my ldap server, an error occured like could not find user: admin. Logs are below. Ldap server should send its information to my openstack environment. Is below warning important?

> ldap_build_search_req ATTRS: cn userPassword enabled sn mail
>   description

How can I handle this situation?

```
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap://localhost/)
ldap_init: trying /etc/ldap/ldap.conf
ldap_init: using /etc/ldap/ldap.conf
ldap_init: HOME env is /var/lib/keystone
ldap_init: trying /var/lib/keystone/ldaprc
ldap_init: trying /var/lib/keystone/.ldaprc
ldap_init: trying ldaprc
ldap_init: LDAPCONF env is NULL
ldap_create
ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap://10.0.0.23)
ldap_sasl_bind
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
ldap_int_open_connection
ldap_connect_to_host: TCP 10.0.0.23:389
ldap_new_socket: 18
ldap_prepare_socket: 18
ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 10.0.0.23:389
ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 18 tm: -1 async: 0
attempting to connect:
connect success
ldap_open_defconn: successful
ldap_send_server_request
ldap_result ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 msgid 1
wait4msg ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 msgid 1 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 msgid 1 all 1
** ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 Connections:
* host: 10.0.0.23  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Thu Jun  1 12:11:40 2017


** ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 1,  origid 1, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 msgid 1 all 1
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 msgid 1 all 1
read1msg: ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 msgid 1 message type bind
read1msg: ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 0 new referrals
read1msg:  mark request completed, ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 msgid 1
request done: ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 msgid 1
res_errno: 0, res_error: <>, res_matched: <>
ldap_free_request (origid 1, msgid 1)
ldap_parse_result
ldap_msgfree
ldap_search_ext
put_filter: "(&(sn=admin)(objectClass=organizationalUnit)(cn=*))"
put_filter: AND
put_filter_list "(sn=admin)(objectClass=organizationalUnit)(cn=*)"
put_filter: "(sn=admin)"
put_filter: simple
put_simple_filter: "sn=admin"
put_filter: "(objectClass=organizationalUnit)"
put_filter: simple
put_simple_filter: "objectClass=organizationalUnit"
put_filter: "(cn=*)"
put_filter: simple
put_simple_filter: "cn=*"
ldap_build_search_req ATTRS: cn userPassword enabled sn mail description
ldap_send_initial_request
ldap_send_server_request
ldap_result ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 msgid 2
wait4msg ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 msgid 2 (infinite timeout)
wait4msg continue ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 msgid 2 all 1
** ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 Connections:
* host: 10.0.0.23  port: 389  (default)
  refcnt: 2  status: Connected
  last used: Thu Jun  1 12:11:40 2017


** ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 Outstanding Requests:
 * msgid 2,  origid 2, status InProgress
   outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
  ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
** ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 Response Queue:
   Empty
  ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 response count 0
ldap_chkResponseList ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 msgid 2 all 1
ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 NULL
ldap_int_select
read1msg: ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 msgid 2 all 1
read1msg: ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 msgid 2 message type search-result
read1msg: ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 0 new referrals
read1msg:  mark request completed, ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 msgid 2
request done: ld 0x7f0e31c9b150 msgid 2
res_errno: 0, res_error: <>, res_matched: <>
ldap_free_request (origid 2, msgid 2)
ldap_parse_result
ldap_msgfree
2017-06-01 12:11:40.512893 2017-06-01 12:11:40.512 5767 WARNING keystone.auth.plugins.core [req-07b3f423-d9fd-419a-836c-2d59fb53ac9d - - - - -] Could not find user: admin
2017-06-01 12:11:40.513608 2017-06-01 12:11:40.513 5767 WARNING keystone.common.wsgi [req-07b3f423-d9fd-419a-836c-2d59fb53ac9d - - - - -] Authorization failed. Could not find user: admin (Disable insecure_debug mode to suppress these det$
```

My keystone.ldap.conf like below

```
[identity]
driver = keystone.identity.backends.ldap.Identity
[assignment]
driver = keystone.assignment.backends.sql.Assignment
[ldap]
url = ldap://10.0.0.23
suffix = dc=openstack,dc=org
user = cn=admin,dc=openstack,dc=org
password = toor
user_tree_dn = ou=Users,dc=openstack,dc=org
user_objectclass = organizationalUnit
group_tree_dn = ou=Groups,dc=openstack,dc=org
group_objectclass = organizationalUnit
use_dumb_member = True
dumb_member = keystone_ldap
page_size = 0
alias_dereferencing = always
query_scope = sub
```

EDIT: Ldap structure

```
# openstack.org
dn: dc=openstack,dc=org
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: openstack
dc: openstack

# admin, openstack.org
dn: cn=admin,dc=openstack,dc=org
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: admin
description: LDAP administrator

# Groups, openstack.org
dn: ou=Groups,dc=openstack,dc=org
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: groups

# Users, openstack.org
dn: ou=Users,dc=openstack,dc=org
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: users
```

**EDIT:**
Inside keystone.conf I did not add any sn property but ldap always searching sn=admin as filter.

> filter="(&(sn=admin)(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(cn=*))"

Also I added ldap admin as user field of keystone.conf . Ldap searches this admin user inside user_tree but admin is not included user_tree. If someone knows working mechanism of keystone ldap, then problem could be easily solved.

Comment: I added the a comment on my answer following the new info you provided

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `user_objectclass = organizationalUnit` , I don't think the user is an `ou` , it is more likely a `inetOrgPerson`, or `Person` or something referencing a user and not an organization

It generates a filter like : `"(sn=admin)(objectClass=organizationalUnit)"` which will never find your entry. Check the objectclass of the user admin to change with the right value.

Edit : From your newly posted info : Try : `user_objectclass = organizationalRole`

You will experience the same problem with the groups if they have not the `organizationalUnit` objectClass.

Edit 2 : Also the admin user is not located in the subtree set by the option `user_tree_dn`

If you want the admin user to be part of the selection of users, try this configuration :

```
[ldap]
url = ldap://10.0.0.23
suffix = dc=openstack,dc=org
user = cn=admin,dc=openstack,dc=org
password = toor
user_tree_dn = dc=openstack,dc=org
user_filter = (|(cn=admin)(objectClass=inetOrgPerson))
group_tree_dn = ou=Groups,dc=openstack,dc=org
group_objectclass = organizationalUnit
use_dumb_member = True
dumb_member = keystone_ldap
page_size = 0
alias_dereferencing = always
query_scope = sub
```

I put a filter to match the `admin` entry and the future users entries. If these entries are not `inetOrgPerson` but another objectClass, feel free to modify it accordingly.

Note : Any `inetOrgPerson` entry under the subtree `dc=openstack,dc=org` will be considered a user.

For more informations about the Openstack integration with ldap, see [this doc](https://docs.openstack.org/admin-guide/identity-integrate-with-ldap.html)

Comment: Error still exists

Comment: Can you provide the log of the ldap directory with the new configuration? To see what filters are used to look for the admin user. In the previous log, the filters contain `(sn=admin)` could you try also to add the `sn=admin` attribute to your entry?

Comment: @setr Could you try setting the attribute `sn` with the value `admin` and retry ?

Comment: @setr Could you try to do a ldapsearch with the credential used by openstack with the filter `"(&(sn=admin)(objectClass=organizationalRole)(cn=*))"` ? Do you get a result ?

Comment: ldapsearch -x -b "dc=openstack,dc=org" "(&(sn=admin)(objectClass=organizationalRole)(cn=*))"
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=openstack,dc=org> with scope subtree
# filter: (&(sn=admin)(objectClass=organizationalRole)(cn=*))
# requesting: ALL
#

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 1

Comment: @setr I was so obsessed by the wrong filter I didn't check the others configuration fields. Retry you ldapsearch with the `-b` option set to the `user_tree_dn` : `-b "ou=Users,dc=openstack,dc=org"` . The `admin` entry is not in this subtree so won't be found ;)

Comment: Yes ldapsearch -x -b "ou=Users,dc=openstack,dc=org" does not returns admin because is not in this subtree. How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Either put your admin user in this subtree or change the keystone configuration to match all the users you need. I'll edit my answer with an example

Comment: @setr "Not working" is not really helpful ;) do the logs changed? Is there a new error? Etc. ^^

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145720/discussion-between-setr-and-esteban).

Comment: Do we have to send LDAP user as user inside keystone conf? I could not understand which user should be sent.

Comment: And why always add conn=1052 op=1 SRCH base="dc=openstack,dc=org" scope=1 deref=0 filter="(&(sn=admin)(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(cn=*))"  sn inside filter

Answer (score 0):

According to the below source code keystone adds filter

> filter="(&(sn=admin)(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(cn=*))"

if you do not specify user_name_attribute. Make

```
user_name_attribute=cn
```

https://github.com/openstack/keystone/blob/master/keystone/conf/ldap.py